# How to make children their height wrap within a flexbox parent

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to find the correct answer for a while but didn't really know the right words to look for.

**Example**
[image]

**Expected Example**
[image]

I'm currently having trouble where the children containers are being set to the height of the parent (which is currently defined by a child).

**Code**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='container'>
    Line 1<br>Line 2
  </div>
  
  <div class='container'>
    Line 1
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtjq6fa3/)

Comment: just use  `align-items: flex-start;` in wrapper class

Answer (score 1):

You could do either:

- Add `align-items: flex-start` to the parent `.wrapper` definition
- Add `align-self: flex-start` to the child `.container` definition

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='container'>
    Line 1<br>Line 2
  </div>
  
  <div class='container'>
    Line 1
  </div>
</div>
```

From CSS tricks, [align-items](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/):
The `align-items` property defines the default behavior for how items are laid out along the cross axis (perpendicular to the main axis).

Also from CSS tricks, [align-self](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-self/):
`align-self` will affect the specific child of a flex element

Answer (score 0):

use `height:max-content;` so u can achieve your aim, try snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;

}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='container'>
    Line 1<br>Line 2
  </div>
  
  <div class='container'>
    Line 1
  </div>
</div>
```